# position marker keeps going on false route before rerouting HERE maps premium sdk

Tags: android, here-api

is it possible on here android sdk to force positioning marker to stop before calculating new route?

we tested this case which other navigations their marker stops then continue on new route but here positioning marker indepentently moving along a wrong path even the car turned to another street.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this API. [NavigationManager#setMapUpdateMode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-guidance-navigationmanager.html#topic-apiref__setmapupdatemode-navigationmanager-mapupdatemode). It takes an enum [MapUpdateMode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-guidance-navigationmanager-mapupdatemode.html#topic-apiref). If you use POSITION or POSITION_ANIMATION it should do what you are suggesting.

This feature is called map matached navigation with extrapolation. The extrapolation is what is causing the marker to keep moving.

Comment: we are using ROADVIEW mapupdateMode as it suit for driving navigation mode. So we have to switch between modes when reroure calculation started ?